# Group data In MOngoDB with Spring Boot based on Day as Sunday Monday from Date with Occurance count of document based on a Field

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a data collection as below & I want to fetch data based on Day for a perticular date given on document & On same day Occurance of Document with respect to a perticular field as filterName.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("6406e56d18ab204cfe6b7915"),
"timeStamp" : ISODate("2023-03-07"),
"filterName" : "ABC1"
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("6406e56d18ab204cfe6b7915"),
"timeStamp" : ISODate("2023-03-07"),
"filterName" : "ABC2"
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("6406e56d18ab204cfe6b7915"),
"timeStamp" : ISODate("2023-03-07"),
"filterName" : "ABC2"
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("6406e56d18ab204cfe6b7915"),
"timeStamp" : ISODate("2023-03-06"),
"filterName" : "ABC3"
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("6406e56d18ab204cfe6b7915"),
"timeStamp" : ISODate("2023-03-05"),
"filterName" : "ABC3"
}


[
{
"id": "**Sunday**",
"countOccurance": [
{
**"ABC3": 1**
}
]
},
{
"id": "**Monday**",
"countOccurance": [
{
**"ABC3": 1**
}
]
},
{
"id": "**Tuesday**",
"countOccurance": [
{
**"ABC1": 1,
"ABC2": 2**
}
]
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.notification.aggregate([
{$match: {timeStamp: {$gte: new Date(Date.now() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)}}},
{$group: {_id: { $dayOfWeek: { date: "$timeStamp" }},data: {$push: {k: "$filterName",v: { $sum: 1 }}}}},
{$project: {data: {$arrayToObject: "$data"}}},
{$sort: { "_id": 1 }}
])
```